# using a ForEach loop in powershell to sort in excel

Tags: html, excel, powershell

I am new to powershell, so I could really use some help with a script I am trying to develop.

I have been tasked to create a powershell script that clears the data from one of the columns and renames it.  After that it looks at the data in the column and any time it finds a match in the data, it adds a embedded URL to the column.

I was able to complete the first part of the script; however, I am out of ideas on how to pull off the second part of the script.

Therefore, I would greatly appreciate any help or references that may help me work through this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please show some specific code with a specific problem that we can assist with.

Answer (score 0):

I Dont know why specifically you want to sort the table based on usage of For-Each,
Rather i would suggest a powerful command in powershell Sort-Object,Feed it the object and specify the sorting criterion.

Visit this:[Order Your Output by Easily Sorting Objects in PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/01/10/order-your-output-by-easily-sorting-objects-in-powershell/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will definitely check this out

Comment: Ok, I am changing paths on this.  The problem I am having now is that I can seem to get the excel sheet to sort the dates from newest to the oldest.  There are other steps that I would like to accomplish in the script, but I do not know where to start....

Comment: If this answer helped upvote it,and with a detailed explanation of things you want to accomplish raise a different question.

Answer (score 0):

```
`#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -----------------------
 # PowerShell to filter by strings

 Get-Content C:\Users\cobre\Desktop\PowerShell\Out-ExcelPivotTable\john1.csv 
 | Where{$_ -notmatch "adobe"} | Out-File 
 C:\Users\cobre\Desktop\PowerShell\Out-ExcelPivotTable\john12.csv -Encoding 
 ascii –Force
 Get-Content C:\Users\cobre\Desktop\PowerShell\OutExcelPivotTable\john12.csv 
 | Where{$_ -match "microsoft"} | Out-File 
 C:\Users\cobre\Desktop\PowerShell\Out-ExcelPivotTable\john123.csv -Encoding 
 ascii –Force
 Get-Content C:\Users\cobre\Desktop\PowerShell\Out-
 ExcelPivotTable\john123.csv | sort -Descending | Out-File 
 C:\Users\cobre\Desktop\PowerShell\Out-ExcelPivotTable\john1234.csv -
 Encoding ascii –Force 

 #Moves entire row down 
 $xlShiftDown = -4121
 $strPath="C:\Users\cobre\Desktop\PowerShell\Out-
 ExcelPivotTable\john1234.csv"
 $objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
 $objExcel.Visible=$true
 $WorkBook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strPath) 
 $worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item("john1234")


 $eRow = $worksheet.cells.item(1,1).entireRow
 $active = $eRow.activate()
 $active = $eRow.insert($xlShiftDown)

 #Create a header for KB Report; set each cell to Bold and add a background 
 color
 $row = 1
 $Column = 1
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'Release Date' 
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).Interior.ColorIndex =48
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).HorizontalAlignment = -4108
 $worksheet.columns.item('a').NumberFormat = "MMM yyyy"

 $row = 1
 $Column = 2
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'IAVM Number'
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).Interior.ColorIndex =48
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).HorizontalAlignment = -4108

 $row = 1
 $Column = 3
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'Description'
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).Interior.ColorIndex =48
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).HorizontalAlignment = -4108

 $row = 1
 $Column = 4
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'CVEs'
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).Interior.ColorIndex =48
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).HorizontalAlignment = -4108

 $row = 1
 $Column = 5
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column)= 'KBs & Articles'
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).Interior.ColorIndex =48
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).Font.Bold=$True
 $objExcel.Cells.Item($row,$column).HorizontalAlignment = -4108

 #Set up a header filter
 $headerRange = $objExcel.Range("a1","e1")
 $headerRange.AutoFilter() | Out-Null

 #Increment Row and reset Column back to first column
 $row++
 $Column = 1


 #Need to capture text with hyperlinks and move to empty cell or sheet
 #Need to copy hyperlink and truncate all but KB numbers and the end of link
 #Need to embed hyperlinks into cell with KB numbers


 #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ----------'
```

Comment: Okay @John,to help u on this,we may need data. And looking at the things you are trying you might wanna use excel macros,Record them.And then Trigger macros using powershell when required(If Powershell is something you want to use it schedule  the task and get regular report generation).else you can use excel to directly Refresh the report.(Suggesting this method,as you are in all the manner using excel objects )

Comment: I will see what I can do about getting data I can upload here.  As far as using macros, it isn't an option as this piece of script will be tied in to automate the process.  the user will not have interaction with the sheet, only the ability to view it on share point

Comment: Yes John,Keep the excel with the macros on SharePoint,and let Powershell script trigger those macros and fetch the required data using powershell itsef,I had same problem in last month.We solved it like this. 1)Kept the excel with macro on sharepoint  with all the required calculations 2)Triggered the macro from powershell.3)Used powershell to specifically fetch the required data and pushed it to another sharepoint file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I am totally lost.  I need to do the following:

Capture text with hyperlinks and move to empty cell or sheet
                                                                                          Copy hyperlink and truncate all but KB numbers and the end of link

Copy to embed hyperlinks into cell with KB numbers

The cell that I need to sort is in the following format:

https://support.microsoft.com/help/4023307https://support.microsoft.com/help/4023307https://support.microsoft.com/help/4023307https://support.microsoft.com/help/4023307